# Certain DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.AutoSize values leads to System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, runtime-error, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I work in Visual Studio v12.0.31101 Update 4, .NET Framework v.4.5.50938.

There's a DataGridView with some TextBox columns and one ComboBox column. DGV is binded to some DataTable, Combobox is binded to another DataTable. Everything works fine, until I set ComboBoxColumn.AutoSize paratemer to one of these values:

- AllCells
- AllCellsExceptHeader
- DisplayedCells
- DisplayedCellsExceptHeader

In that case I get DataGridView exception: SystemArgumentException: Illegal value in DataGridViewComboBoxCell.

Does it mean I shouldn't use these parameters with ComboBoxColumn or there's a workaround?

Comment: That error usually indicates that one of the values set in your `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`s is not included in the selection set.

Comment: @Jason Faulkner I change only one property: AutoSize. With some values I get error, with others - I don't.